# Investigating slow SQL performance, seeing different CREATE PROCEDURE repeatedly

Tags: sql-server

I'm using Bret Ozar's First Responder Kit, sp_WhoIsActive, and some other tools to investigate some slowness my web app is experiencing. I repeatedly see "CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProceedureName]" followed by the create script for this plan.

My first thought was that this is what happens when the plan cache needs to be rebuilt, and this is a symptom of not enough memory/long-running queries;

Can anyone verify that this is the case? 
Or does anyone know what this is actually indicative of?

Thank you!

Comment: This is normal when a stored procedure is executing. To see the specific statement in the stored procedure that is executing you need to use `statement_start_offset, statement_end_offset` from `sys.dm_exec_requests`

Answer (score -2):

This is happening, when you use temporary tables in procedure. Because of that the procedure is being recompiled.

Comment: this is not the case